# VBScript/SQL Server Runs to point, then returns syntax error at certain line

Tags: sql, arrays, sql-server, vbscript, syntax-error

not sure how much info I can provide as this is a live sensitive database.

I'm recovering my predecessors code.

There is a VBS file that checks emails from table 1, uses a split statement after the '@' to get the domain, then checks to see if that domain exists in other tables. If so, pull some fields from those matching tables, then update a 3rd table where the email address is matched.

So far as I can tell one of the arrays/tables created for matching against is 20,000 records long. However the script runs, then fails at a particular email address/record number, citing Incorrect Syntax near ' s'.

Again, not overly familiar with vbscript, and quite rusty with my SQL. Can anyone advise what might be the problem? Thought it was a query time out issue, but the server is set to no time limit for queries.

Script below:

```
'START - Delete
set rsDelete = conn.execute("DELETE FROM JofTest_emailTrackDump")
set rsDelete = nothing
'END - Delete

'START - Update
set rsUpdate = conn.execute("INSERT INTO JofTest_emailTrackDump (emailTrack_email) SELECT DISTINCT emailIP_emailAddress AS emailTrack_email FROM JofTest_emailIP WHERE emailIP_emailAddress <> '' AND emailIP_hide = 0 AND emailIP_emailAddress IS NOT NULL AND emailIP_emailAddress NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT emailIP_emailAddress2 FROM ((SELECT DISTINCT rec_email_company AS emailIP_emailAddress2 FROM JofTest_crm_company_master WHERE rec_email_company <> '' AND rec_email_company IS NOT NULL) UNION (SELECT DISTINCT rec_email_direct AS emailIP_emailAddress2 FROM JofTest_crm_company_master WHERE rec_email_direct <> '' AND rec_email_direct IS NOT NULL) UNION (SELECT DISTINCT rec_email_additional AS emailIP_emailAddress2 FROM JofTest_crm_company_master WHERE rec_email_additional <> '' AND rec_email_additional IS NOT NULL) UNION (SELECT DISTINCT contact_email_primary AS emailIP_emailAddress2 FROM JofTest_crm_contacts_masters WHERE contact_email_primary <> '' AND contact_email_primary IS NOT NULL) ) A) ORDER BY emailIP_emailAddress ")
set rsUpdate = nothing
'END - Update

'START - Find Partial Match
set rsPartialList = conn.execute("SELECT DISTINCT emailIP_emailAddress AS emailTrack_email FROM JofTest_emailIP WHERE emailIP_emailAddress <> '' AND emailIP_hide = 0 AND emailIP_emailAddress IS NOT NULL AND emailIP_emailAddress NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT emailIP_emailAddress2 FROM ((SELECT DISTINCT rec_email_company AS emailIP_emailAddress2 FROM JofTest_crm_company_master WHERE rec_email_company <> '' AND rec_email_company IS NOT NULL) UNION (SELECT DISTINCT rec_email_direct AS emailIP_emailAddress2 FROM JofTest_crm_company_master WHERE rec_email_direct <> '' AND rec_email_direct IS NOT NULL) UNION (SELECT DISTINCT rec_email_additional AS emailIP_emailAddress2 FROM JofTest_crm_company_master WHERE rec_email_additional <> '' AND rec_email_additional IS NOT NULL) UNION (SELECT DISTINCT contact_email_primary AS emailIP_emailAddress2 FROM JofTest_crm_contacts_masters WHERE contact_email_primary <> '' AND contact_email_primary IS NOT NULL) ) A) ORDER BY emailIP_emailAddress")
while not rsPartialList.eof

    'START - Make Host
    if instr(rsPartialList("emailTrack_email"), "@") > -1 then

        arrHost = split(rsPartialList("emailTrack_email"), "@")

        if ubound(arrHost) > 0 then

            emailAddressHost = arrHost(1)

            'START - Find Partial Match
            set rsFindPartial = conn.execute("SELECT rec_id, rec_company FROM crm_company_masters LEFT JOIN crm_contacts_masters ON contact_recID = rec_id WHERE (rec_email_company LIKE '%" & emailAddressHost & "' OR rec_email_direct LIKE '%" & emailAddressHost & "' OR rec_email_additional LIKE '%" & emailAddressHost & "' OR contact_email_primary LIKE '%" & emailAddressHost & "')")
            if not rsFindPartial.eof then

                'START - Update Dump With Partial Match Info
                set rsUpdatePartial = conn.execute("UPDATE emailTrackDump SET emailTrack_partialRecID = " & rsFindPartial("rec_id") & ", emailTrack_partialCompany = '" & rsFindPartial("rec_company") & "' WHERE emailTrack_email = '" & rsPartialList("emailTrack_email") & "'")

                'END - Update Dump With Partial Match Info

                varCount = varCount + 1

            end If
            rsFindPartial.close()
            set rsFindPartial = nothing
            'END - Find Partial Match

        end if
    end If
    For Each field In arrHost
   Wscript.Echo field
   Next



    'END - Make Host

rsPartialList.movenext()
wend
rsPartialList.close()
set rsPartialList = nothing
'END - Find Partial Match

'Close Connection
conn.close()
set conn = nothing
```

Failure happens on row 33, character 17 `set rsUpdatePartial = conn.execute("UPDATE email....`

EDIT - also by removing pieces I was able to get the code to run. The piece i removed was the section titled `Update Dump with Partial Match Info`, so i have to assume the error lies within there.

Comment: You probably have some weird characters in source fields (like a single quote) that is confusing the final concatenated string. If you were to print it out you'd see it. The proper solution is to turn this cursor based abomination into a stored procedure.

Comment: That's what i'm thinking, i'm looking at the database tables, particularly the row where it stops and those under it, any idea which table may give me the data i'm looking for? Bearing in mind JofTest_EmailIP contains some 800,00 non unique rows....

Comment: I would look for an apostrophe in your data. You are doing something like `somefield = '%" & vbavariable & "%' more sql;"` If that vbavariable contains an apostrophe then your SQL is getting all funkied up. It would be better if you used command parameters here to put together that sql statement to avoid this. Or, you could do `Replace(emailAddressHost, "'", "''")` when putting that variable in the sql statement so the single apostrophe is escaped in the sql string.

Comment: By far the biggest issue here is that you are wide open to sql injection. Using replace as @JNevill suggests is a joke. You can't fix the problem with character replacement. You need to use parameterized queries. It prevents sql injection and fixes this problem all at the same time. You should NEVER EVER EVER build up a string like that and execute it. My friend bobby tables loves that kind of thing. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: The dodgy data is probably in the company field. Probably the easiest way to find it is to add this line before the _Dump with Partial Match Info_ line: `Wscript.Echo rsFindPartial("rec_company") & " " & rsPartialList("emailTrack_email")` and see what it crashes on. You should consider rewriting this as an internal stored procedure which will run much faster

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure how to nominate the correct answer here, you were all right that it was a dodgy character, but particular thanks to Nick McDermaid for providing the line to find it.

Fully understand the need to avoid this kind scripting, and i'm friends with little Bobby Tables. As stated this is my predecessors code slapped together to find matching domains for GDPR compliance, it just runs to provide a data cleanser a list of records to validate.

Thanks to everyone for your assistance.

Kind regards,

Jl